# Number of vertices of a polygon

Tags: geometry

for an equilateral triangle to be formed by joining the vertices of a regular polygon, why does the number of vertices need to be a multiple of 3 ?

For instance, if its given that 9 equilateral triangles can be formed by joining the vertices of an n-sided polygon , why does the number of vertices need to be 27 ?

Comment: Apologies - corrected

Comment: In the first sentence, are you specifically asking about _equilateral_ triangles?

Comment: @Arthur Yes ,equilateral triangles

Answer (score 0):

Let's inscribe those polygons in a circumference.
In every equilateral triangle, the angles are of $60$ degrees, and since that is an angle inscribed in the circumference, there must be two vertices in an angle of $120$ degrees with the center of the circle, and that implies that $3$ divides the number of vertices of the polygon.

[image]

Comment: What if two vertices are common to more than one equilateral triangle ?

Comment: That is not possible

Comment: How would we prove that :)